# Cross site scripting when the greater than and less than signs are escaped?

Tags: xss, sql-injection, injection

If a website encodes `<` to `&lt;` and `>` becomes `&gt;`, is it still possible to perform cross site scripting? What would you enclose the script tags in?

For example, on one of my sites I can use `<script>alert(1)</script>` normally, but how can I do the same thing when encoding takes place?

Comment: It could still be possible if parameters are directly used in javascript without being sanitized. I'd recommend to use output encoding all the time, not just for the characters < and >.

Answer (score 22):

Oh yes it is!

Consider this HTML:

```
<a href="{{str}}">
```

and consider an input like:

```
" onmouseover="alert('GOTCHA')"
```

You get the picture.

If your javascript is being injected *within* a tag then you don't need the angle brackets. I borrowed this off this similar S/O post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696244/xss-is-escaping-and-sufficient

If you are interested in filter evasion like this consult:

https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet

This has all the common stuff.

As far as safety is concerned: Encode all the things! You never know how clever the attacker is.

Comment: Remember that the console is your friend and enemy. I can watch all the XHR calls and then watch all the parameters being sent. Using the console, you can fake different requests that may bring your system to self-destruction. It's not only the input *in*  the page, but **whatever you send**. Even what you receive must be carefully handled!

Comment: Exactly! Not sure how to incorporate that fact into the post, though.

Comment: honestly, me neither :/ But it would be precious information. Maybe someone who is better at words might be able to make a nice text.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to Cross-site scripting, the most important thing is context. The context in which it gets reflected or stored.I will demonstrate this with a real example from my experience. Once while bug-hunting i noted that a URL parameter was getting reflected inside a variable:

```
http://www.example.com/blah.php?id=test&var=101011
```

The value of var was being reflected in the source of the page at page load, in roughly the following format, inside a script block:

```
var a = "101011";
```

and injecting as much as a '<' would divert the request to the WAF which would throw an error page, so my actual payload to deal with this was:

```
prompt(1)";eval(a);
```

which bypassed the WAF and became a successful case of reflected XSS. So, the payload should be modified according to context and you might not need the tags. Hope that helped.