# XSS without ' > < =

Tags: xss

The developer filter the characters `'`, `<`, `>` and `=` and the vulnerability is something like:

I also tried URL encodes like `%3c`, `%0a`, `%3e`, `%0a`, `%3d`, `%0a`, `%27` and `%0a` but it doesn't work. Without filters I can get XSS like `">alert("aaa")`.

Any ideas about how to bypass?

Comment: Where is your injection point?

Comment: [Related](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/81824/147932)

Comment: Something like `" onclick="..."`?

Comment: going for hover on a screen sized element might work even better.

Comment: @CodesInChaos only if injection point already inside html tag